# Pine Script & Volume Resulting in Two Values

Tags: algorithm, pine-script, alpine-linux, stock, tradingview-api

I am trying to calculate when the volume within a specific day reaches the average volume at a daily timeframe.

```html
dailyVolume = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", volume)
var int dayOfWeek = 0
var float cumVolume = 0 

if dayOfWeek != dayofweek
    dayOfWeek := dayofweek
    cumVolume := 0 


cumVolume := cumVolume + volume
```

The values of dailyVolume and cumVolume are order of magnitudes apart from each other. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same result than you, and then i decided to complete the dayoftheweek with time and the UTC I use in my chart.
The result are way better (but still not equal all the time).

```
//@version=5
indicator("test, overlay=true)

dailyVolume = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", volume)

var float cumVolume = 0 

if dayofweek(time, "UTC+2")[1] != dayofweek(time, "UTC+2")
    label.new(bar_index, close, text=str.tostring(cumVolume), yloc=yloc.abovebar, color=color.white, textcolor=color.black)
    label.new(bar_index, close, text=str.tostring(dailyVolume), yloc=yloc.belowbar, color=color.white, textcolor=color.black)
    cumVolume := 0 


cumVolume := cumVolume + volume
```

[image]